# d3 remove svg opacity

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have an svg rectangle in my force directed layout that appears when you click on a node. I'm wondering how I can set the rect to be fully opaque. I have its opacity property set at 1, but it's still transparent. It's weird as well because I can still manipulate the opacity property to 0.5 for example, and the rect will be come lighter. I can't make it any more opaque than how it is right now though.

```
    var tooltip = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(-300,0)");
  tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("color", "black")
    .attr("opacity", 1);
```

Here's the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/5UKhnYNEaMpbL6O1dNqQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because of the order of the `svg` elements you have placed. You are drawing the rectangle first and then draw the nodes. If you want the rectangles to hide the node. Then you have to draw the `rect` after drawing the nodes.

Comment: Just gave that a shot, it seems like nothing has changed. http://plnkr.co/edit/5UKhnYNEaMpbL6O1dNqQ?p=preview

Comment: It happens because you have drawn the nodes after drawing the rectangle.